# What is the best way to log a .NET Func<>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a generic method that accepts a `Func<int>` and I would like to log the Func that is passed into the method. What properties are available on the passed in func to help me understand what it is doing?

Comment: Use `Expression<Func<T>>` instead of just `Func<int>`.

Comment: The best I would expect you to get is the `MethodInfo` which has quite a few details. Somehow I don't expect that this is what you want.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to "log" the function? Isn't the debugger good enough? Or maybe unit tests?

Comment: @Jaroslav - Analyzing the expression tree will take quite a bit of work...

Comment: @John - Logging and reporting feedback to the user.

Comment: @Detroit: maybe you should say something about who this is for, and why, because logging a function, in general, makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jaroslav Jandek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379714/jaroslav-jandek) pointed out by using `Expression<Func<T>>` I can get more information about the method being passed in. Specifically: I found that the `body` property has the anonymous method signature as a string.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body.aspx](http://ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can log the method name with `func.Method.Name`, and there's some other useful properties in the `MethodInfo` class. However, if the `Func` is anonymous, then you will not get a very helpful name.

Comment: +1. You could obviously still log the name of an anonymous function, but it won't be particularly helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying.